# How do i fade one div out and fade one in with a click of one element? HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a paragraph of text to fade out, and another one to take its place when I click on an href in my code.

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="switch"">Espanol</a>

<p class="english">This is an english paragraph</p>
<p class="spanish">Se es la espanol pargrafio</p>
```

CSS

```
.spanish {
    display: none;  
}
.english {
    display: block; 
}
```

Jquery

```
$("#switch").click(function(){
    $("p.spanish").show();
    $("p.english").hide();
})
```

Now all I want is one to disappear and another to appear in its place with one click, but this code is not working, please help!

Comment: Incidentally, you have two double-quotes following the word 'switch' in the `id` attribute. This causes problems as it closes and then immediately starts a new string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a callback within the `hide()` or, as in the example `fadeOut()` function:

```
$('#switch').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('p.english').fadeOut(
            function(){
                $('p.spanish').fadeIn();
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MHY2a/).

---

**Edited** with a slightly improved version of the above:

```
$('#switch').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('p.english, p.spanish').fadeToggle(400);
        $(this).text(
            function(){
                if ($(this).text() == 'English'){
                    $(this).text('Espanol');
                }
                else if ($(this).text() == 'Espanol'){
                    $(this).text('English');
                }
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MHY2a/1/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).
- [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).
- [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/).

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="switch"">Español</a>
<a class="english">This is an english paragraph</p>
<p class="spanish hide">Se es la español pargrafio</p>
```

CSS

```
.hide {
  display: none;  
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#switch").click(function(){
  $("p.spanish, p.english").toggleClass("hide");
  $(this).text( $("p.spanish").is(":visible") ? "English" : "Español" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra quote on your markup after `<a href="#" id="switch"` and use something like this:

```
$("#switch").click(function() {
    var toHide = $("p." + ($('p.english').css('display') == 'none' ? 'spanish' : 'english'));
    $(toHide).fadeOut();

    toHide.next().css("margin-top", -1 * toHide.height());
    toHide.next().fadeIn(function() {
        toHide.next().css("margin-top", "auto");
        toHide.insertAfter(toHide.next());
    });

    return false;
});
```

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jqKe6/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it fixes the problem, but replace `id="switch""` with `id="switch"`